# How to block a notification that comes through based on a SharedPreferences value?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a SharedPreference: `sharedPref.getBoolean("online", false)`

If I get a Notification whilst `online` is false, I want to block it. Typically there won't be a notification if the user is offline but very occasionally I get one, and I'd like this as a backup to prevent the notification.

The notification is sent via [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) and here is how it's processed in my application:

```
class CustomApplication : Application() {

    val MATCH_CHANNEL_ID = "MATCH_CHANNEL"

    companion object {
        var database: AppDatabase? = null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val settings: FirebaseFirestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().setPersistenceEnabled(false).build()
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().firestoreSettings = settings
        CustomApplication.database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "AppDatabase").build()
        createNotificationChannel()
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val matchChannel = NotificationChannel(MATCH_CHANNEL_ID, "Nearby matches", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            matchChannel.description = "Nearby matches"
            val manager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(matchChannel)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can prevent notifications coming in if `online` is false in SharedPreferences?

EDIT:

When I get the notification FCM in the background, it calls . `FirebaseMessagingService.onCreate()`:

```
class CustomFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "CustomFirebaseMessagingService onCreate()")
        return
        super.onCreate()
    }
```

I've overwritten `onCreate()` to return before `super.onCreate()` - in the hopes of cancelling the notification. However, the notification still fires.

is there another function in `CustomFirebaseMessagingService()` I can override to intercept the notification and cancel it?

Comment: you can put your notification manager inside the if statement

Comment: How so? Doesn't `manager.createNotificationChannel(matchChannel)` just create the Notification Channel but not process future notifications?

Comment: Did you use a service that extends FirebaseMessagingService?

Comment: @Zorgan `createNotificationChannel` only creates the Channel that the user can customise in the notification settings of the application (System too) , but creating the notification is a different process , you can find it as suggested by other in the FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: set flag and check if it is coming from firebase or shared preferences..

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your question correctly, you're talking about the situation when you're receiving push messages when your app isn't running. You've mentioned that `onMessageReceived()` only gets called when your app is in running state, but your notifications are displayed even without this method being called by the system. Therefore, we can conclude that those notifications are drawn by the system automatically. This behavior is controlled by "notification" and "data" sections in the body of your FCM message.

FCM messages have a complicated specification that can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages). But since we're only interested in "notification" and "data" sections, we can depend on their behavior:

**First case - both "notification" and "data" sections are present**

Example:

```
{
  "message":{
    "notification": { /*...*/ },
    "data": {/*...*/}
  }
}
```

In this case if your app is in background state,

- The system will automatically show a notification;
- If this notification is clicked, an activity will be launched;
- The intent for the activity will contain "data" body and some technical information about the FCM message.

**Second case - only "notification" section is present**

Example:

```
{
  "message":{
    "notification": { /*...*/ },
  }
}
```

In this case if your app is in background state,

- The system will automatically show a notification;
- If this notification is clicked, an activity will be launched;
- The intent for the activity will contain **only** technical information about the FCM message.

**Third case - only "data" section is present**

Example:

```
{
  "message":{
    "data": {/*...*/}
  }
}
```

In this case if your app is in background state,

- The system **will not** show a notification automatically;
- `onMessageReceived()` will be called.

So, having looked through this information, you can try changing the body of your FCM message(i.e. throwing away "notification" section) to disallow the system to handle draw notifications by itself.

Having your messages being handled by `onMessageReceived()` **every time**, you can put your logic with that flag there.

Comment: Thanks this explains it well. However I'm looking to disable notifications based on local data (SharedPreferences data), not on the FCM body.

Comment: Doing so you will receive all push messages in your `Service` and there you will be able to apply your logic. The thing is that modifying the structure of your message will give you an ability to control everything on your own instead of allowing the system to do something automatically. Now your problem exists because the system shows those notifications by itself when the app is offline. By throwing out "notification" part of the message you will tell the system that you want to handle push messages (i.e. show notifications) by yourself

Answer (score 0):

See your manifest file there will be a service like that

```
<service
    android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Then goto `MyFirebaseMessagingService.java` file and check your shared preference value and set your condition for notification. Try this..

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    boolean flag = sharedPref.getBoolean("online", false);

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

          if(flag){
             //TODO write your code here to set notification and notify
          }

    }

}
```

Comment: onMessageReceived() only gets called when inside the app - I need to block the notification in the background.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <service
        android:name=".fcm.FCMService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:stopWithTask="false"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

not really well documented but setting it to false will keep the service alive even if the app is in background or stopped
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#stopWithTask

this way you can handle the blocking in the on msg received method as suggested by the previous poster

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_QA_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notif)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
               .bigText(text)
            );

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LauncherActivty.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    //use the bundled url if it is there and we have more then 1 notification for this type
    if(amount > 1 && !bundledURL.equals("")){
        intent.putExtra("url", bundledURL);
    }else{
        intent.putExtra("url", url);
    }

    intent.putExtra("notification_group", notificationGroup);
    intent.putExtra("notification_group_id", notificationGroupID);
    intent.putExtra("notification_id", notificationID);
    intent.putExtra("is_group", isGroup);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationGroup, Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I just added `android:stopWithTask="false"` and it still didn't call `onMessagedReceived()` in the background

Comment: hm okay that is weird because for my project it works, I create all the notifications manually in the FCMService and it works both when the app is in background and closed completely.

did you remove the return statement in the creation before testing?

Comment: Yes I removed the `return` statement. What do you mean you created the notifications manually? I created mine via Cloud Functions

Comment: All notifications I create are done inside the msg received, basically I do only get data "push" notifications from fcm and then create the notification with the builder:

put the actual creation of a notification into the main answer for readability ;)